# how to remove the header line of .txt file while not disturbing the rest of the line in matlab

Tags: matlab

respected all,

here I have a problem reading a .txt file into my matlab program. My instrument is giving the data as

ABSOLUTE REFERNCE AEROSOL SAMPLER $    1 2 149; $    2 3 183; $    3 3 191; $    4 3 210;

I have to read it and write it to excel. I am using the following code to read the data from the file but it is giving error.

```
[filename,pathname] = uigetfile('*.txt','SELECT THE RAW DATA FILE');
filepath = fullfile(pathname,filename);
fid = fopen(filepath);
c = textscan(fid,'$%n%n%n;','headerlines','1');
```

any one please suggest me on how to remove the header part in my .txt file, without disturbing the rest of the line.

Comment: how is the rest of the file formatted, is it a CSV?

Comment: 1.) What error do you get? 2.) Are there line-breaks in your file, or is it one line (as you show in your question)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) and ignore the first columns of the cell array it returns:

some.txt:

```
myheader 156
myheader 158
```

Code:

```
fileID = fopen('some.txt');
C = textscan(fileID,'%s %f', 'delimiter',' ');
fclose(fileID);
celldisp(C)
```

returns:

```
C{1}{1} =

myheader


C{1}{2} =

myheader


C{2} =

   156
   158
```

Comment: textscan has an input option Headerlines which specifically deals with this. See `help textscan`